# What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

For a while now, I've used phpMyAdmin to manage my local MySQL databases. One thing I'm starting to pick up is the correct character sets for my database. I've decided UTF-8 is the best for compatibility (as my XHTML templates are served as UTF-8) but one thing that confuses me is the varied options for UTF-8 I'm presented with in the phpMyAdmin interface?

The two I've isolate are:

- utf8_general_ci
- utf8_unicode_ci

So my question is this: what is the difference between the `general` and `unicode` variants of `utf8` in MySQL? (I've come to learn that `ci` is shorthand for case-insensitive)

Any help would be most grateful in this matter.

Comment: The short answer is that `utf8_general_ci` is broken for Unicode text, and should not even exist. Never use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MySQL manual on Unicode Character Sets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> For any Unicode character set, operations performed using the *_general_ci* collation are faster than those for the *_unicode_ci* collation. For example, comparisons for the *utf8_general_ci* collation are faster, but slightly less correct, than comparisons for *utf8_unicode_ci*. The reason for this is that *utf8_unicode_ci* supports mappings such as expansions; that is, when one character compares as equal to combinations of other characters. For example, in German and some other languages “`ß`” is equal to “`ss`”. *utf8_unicode_ci* also supports contractions and ignorable characters. *utf8_general_ci* is a legacy collation that does not support expansions, contractions, or ignorable characters. It can make only one-to-one comparisons between characters.

See the referenced page for [further information and examples](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html).

Answer (score -2):

The #@%!ing [manual discusses this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)... :)

One of the issues is speed and accuracy of certain operations.